# How to learn chemistry at home?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry

I'm simple man who doesn't know much about anything. I just enjoy my life. Lately I like chemistry a lot. I want to learn chemistry at home. How do you recommend I do it?

Do i need to do chemical experiments to become good at chemistry?

I can learn about reactions with books. For example:

```
O + H2 -> H2O
```

Also organic chemistry like

```
C2H5OH + O2 -> CO2 + H2O
```

What else do I need to learn? What do chemists do all day if all formulas can be calculated on paper?

How does chemist invent new materials?

Can I be theoretical chemist?

Is this a good hobby choice?

Comment: Buy a chemistry set! (:

Comment: [This](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/24708/how-do-i-excel-in-chemistry) is relevant; but I'm afraid your question is *primarily opinion-based*; we are chemists (exclude me, I'm a semi-chemist); not private counselors.